# How to do FLAC or mpeg with python

Tags: python, audio, data-conversion

I'm looking for python code that can convert .wav or other format to FLAC or mpeg. I hope there is one that doesn't depend on other binaries or libraries and just pure python so that it can run independently anywhere where python is installed ie also serverside. Do you know any examples?

Thanks

Comment: i doubt such a thing exists. why would you ignore existing libraries in order to get something with poor performance?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment! I'm restricted to pure python with no C libraries in this case. I suppose Java could be an alternative. With performance if you mean time it's no problem if very slow conversion. I didn't find a python implementation that didn't rely on binaries.

Comment: @Nick Rosencrantz IMHO Just out of pure interest what is the use of converting wav to flac? Your wav files are most likely lossless and flac is also lossless so why go through the trouble of conversion? It would be more useful to convert wav to ogg or some such container file. I wrote such a program using python and oggenc as well as shntools and cuetools to convert flac or other lossless data to ogg. If you want that I could post it

Comment: Like the others have said, a pure-Python implementation of a FLAC or MPEG (which codec btw?) would be slow and non-trivial to implement. I see two solutions: a) try to compile `python-flac` with the FLAC library as a static library (for the architecture of your server), or b) implement an encoding service (XMLRPC, SOAP, REST, whatever) on another server, where you are free to install the necessary dependencies for `python-flac`.

Comment: @wagner-felix WAV files *usually* contain hi-quality uncompressed PCM sampled audio. FLAC is a method of losslessly compressing audio data so that the file size is reduced. It is quite normal to use FLAC to compress PCM audio such as CD tracks. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python Audio Tools](http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/) seems to fit your description.

Worst case, you'd have to rip the source code out and go from there.

As others have said, there are other alternatives.

Comment: is it possible to use Python Audio Tools programmatically as a python module?

Comment: yes: http://audiotools.sourceforge.net/programming/index.html